# AVG increase in records compared to previous year

Tags: sql, oracle

`AVG` increase in records based on previous year

```
  SELECT TO_CHAR (Application_Date, 'yyyy'), 
         COUNT (*)
    FROM Services
GROUP BY TO_CHAR (Application_Date, 'yyyy')
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

`AVG` increase in records based on previous year

example:

```
2018 ----- 3000 records - 50% increase
2017 ----- 2000 records - 100% increase

2016 ----- 1000 records - 0% increase
```

Comment: 5000 is a 25% increase over 4000. Where are you getting 35% from? And where does average fit in - you seem to be comparing two values, so what are you averaging?

Comment: Functions `lag()` and `lead()` gives you access to the values in other rows. Or make a self join.

Comment: the numbers are just examples sorry for the confusion (this is written example not the output i got)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the reference to averages is a red-herring, and your 35% example is a typo...

You want to compare the values from two rows, so you can use the `lag()` function to peek at the data for the previous year with:

```
LAG(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY TO_CHAR (Application_Date, 'yyyy'))
```

Then calculate the percentage change as normal, using the current year's count and the previous year's count:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (Application_Date, 'yyyy') AS year,
  COUNT(*) AS year_count,
  100 * (COUNT(*) - LAG(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY TO_CHAR (Application_Date, 'yyyy')))
    / LAG(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY TO_CHAR (Application_Date, 'yyyy')) AS percentage_change
FROM Services
GROUP BY TO_CHAR (Application_Date, 'yyyy')
ORDER BY 1 DESC;

YEAR YEAR_COUNT PERCENTAGE_CHANGE
---- ---------- -----------------
2018       5000                25
2017       4000                 0
2016       4000
```

You can format the calculated value however you want (not clear if you want the % sign as part of the result, making it a string, for instance), and you can use coalesce to replace the null value for the first year with zero if you want.

You can also use a CTE or inline view to only do the lag once:

```
SELECT year,
  year_count,
  100 * (year_count - prev_year_count) / prev_year_count AS percentage_change
FROM (
  SELECT TO_CHAR (Application_Date, 'yyyy') AS year,
    COUNT(*) AS year_count,
    LAG(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY TO_CHAR (Application_Date, 'yyyy')) AS prev_year_count
  FROM Services
  GROUP BY TO_CHAR (Application_Date, 'yyyy')
)
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

Personally when using year values I tend to treat them as numbers rather than strings, so I'd use extract:

```
select year,
  year_count,
  100 * (year_count - prev_year_count) / prev_year_count as percentage_change
from (
  select extract(year from application_date) as year,
    count(*) as year_count,
    lag(count(*)) over (order by extract(year from application_date)) as prev_year_count
  from services
  group by extract(year from application_date)
)
order by 1 desc;

      YEAR YEAR_COUNT PERCENTAGE_CHANGE
---------- ---------- -----------------
      2018       5000                25
      2017       4000                 0
      2016       4000
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=eec9d6312a405c1088b74bdc63a66af6)